# How can I set up a rule that affects messages that $string1 AND $string2 in the subjectline?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I receive email messages from an automated utility (sort of a continuous-integration type thing). When the utility runs without error, I get a message with a subject like "Automated Utility Run #1234 Succeeded". When an error condition is encountered, the subject instead resembles "Automated Utility Run #1235 Failed". Unrelatedly, I also receive messages with subjects like "Different Tool Run #1236 Succeeded" and "Different Tool Run #1237 Failed".

I would like to create a rule that only applies to messages with subject lines of the form "Automated Utility Run #1234 Succeeded", and *not* to the other three types of subject lines. Is this possible?

When I use the "with [...] in the subject" condition and specify multiple strings, it automatically ORs them together. I would like to be able to AND them together. Alternatively, if I could use a regex or something, that would work too.

(I figure that this is probably not too difficult to do in VBA, but I really want to keep all of my email-filtering logic in the rules engine if at all possible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rule exceptions for that. Create a rule that checks the subject for "Automated Utility Run #" and add exception for subjects containing " Failed".